# How to return some data from a callback function, that is present inside another function in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**router.js** 
I have a function named controller, this is being called here -

```js
let data = controller();
```

**controller.js**

```js
function controller() {

//sendData below is a promise defined in another file, which is reading content of file and sending the data
sendData().then((data) => {
   //perform some action on data
   console.log(data)
   return data;

   }).catch((err) => {
      return err;
   })
}
```

The data being returned from the controller function is undefined, though i see data to be present in the success callback function on doing console.log

How to correctly return the data from the controller function?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you are assigning a variable to a function your function should return a value. Try adding a return in your controller function.

Comment: while returning from the controller function, undefined gets returned due to the async behavior